# My bundle.js is massive (1.88MiB) and I can't seem to reduce it

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome, minify

I am using Webpack to prepare a production build of my ReactJS website.

I have been following the Webpack docs, but my production build (after minification) is a whopping **1.88MiB**.

```
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). Th
is can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (1.88 MiB)
      bundle.js
```

Using `BundleAnalyzerPlugin` I get this:

[image]

- `bundle.js: 1.88MB (parsed size)`
- `src: 1.04MB (parsed size)`
- `node_modules: 852.17KB (parsed size)`

I don't really get why I am seeing `node_modules/@fortawesome` *inside* `src/js`...

Here is my config:

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.jsx'),
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        from: 'index.html',
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
    ]),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/components'),
      Images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$|.jsx$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|JPG|svg|mov|mp4|webm|ogv)$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=images/&publicPath=/images/', 'image-webpack-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      parallel: true,
      terserOptions: {
        output: {
          comments: false,
        },
      },
      extractComments: false,
    })],
  },
});
```

#### What can I do to reduce the size?

Comment: why do you need jquery with react?

Comment: You'll need to do some code splitting and lazy loading of pages/components/etc.

Comment: Also lift all vendor modules into separate bundle

Comment: corejs is a polyfill lib, check how you can import only what you need.